# MVC and OData, side by side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

We've got a set of MVC apis already in place, but I've been asked to put up OData versions.  I'm trying to co-locate both sets in the same application to share things like custom role providers.  I'm new to OData and so far MVC lessons don't seem to translate directly.

With MVC, we took the generic initialization and managed all the routes with RouteAttribute and I tried to go the same style using ODataRouteAttribute, but all my odata paths come up 404 and the $metadata query returns a 500 saying the configuration hasn't been initialized.

Here's the app start configuration chunk (ODataApiConfig added after the MVC one):

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
ODataApiConfig.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

And here's what's in ODataApiConfig:

```
// OData v7 replacement for configuration.EnableCaseInsensitive(true);
configuration.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata",
        builder =>
                builder.AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", configuration))
                    .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new CaseInsensitiveResolver())
            );

ODataModelBuilder modeler = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modeler.EntitySet<Task>("Tasks");
configuration.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
          routePrefix: "odata",
          model: modeler.GetEdmModel()
);

configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

And here's an example of an api I'm trying to hook up (to get a list of tasks assigned to an employee):

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("v0.1/employee/{userGuid}/tasks")]
[ODataAuthorize(Roles = "Assignee")]
public IHttpActionResult GetMyTasks([FromODataUri]string userGuid)
{
    ...
}
```

So I'm puzzled why
a) A call to ~/odata/$metadata throws a "The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code."  I tried calling EnsureInitialized() at the end of both the OData/MVC initialization and inside the OData initialize routine and it still throws the same error.

b) My ~/odata/employees/{userGuid}/tasks path comes up 404.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** It appears that the ~/odata/$metadata exception is related to the use of [ODataRoute] attributes.  That seems to be enabled by default (and causing the exception); when I tried explicitly creating a routing convention object and DI-ing it, the $metadata exception went away.  Didn't produce much useful, but the exception went away.

The stack trace on the exception is below; I tried breaking on any InvalidOperationExceptions thrown but did not get a break in the debugger

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.get_AttributeMappings()
at System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.SelectControllerName(ODataPath path, HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage request, Object constraint, String parameterName, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)"}
```

**EDIT:** At least I've got an answer on the $metadata call.

My initialization sequence had been informed by this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidhardin/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-lessons-learned/

which said that you had to initialize the Web Api calls first.  I found the opposite.  The above exception came as a result of initializing Web Api first.  When I flipped them, the $metadata call started returning my Task entity set.

Unfortunately, my [ODataRoute] declarations in my TasksController still aren't getting routed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue seems to be that some of the advice in here is out-dated:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidhardin/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-lessons-learned/

Specifically, the $metadata exception turned out to be caused by setting up OData *after* Web API (per the above article).  You have to initialize OData *before* Web Api.

Second, the point about controllers finding differentiation with the route prefix is wrong.  I *did* segregate my web api controllers and odata controllers in different directories and I did  use RoutePrefix/ODataRoutePrefix to put them on different paths.

But after getting the source code for AttributeRoutingConvention from github and using that for debugging, I found the following:

If you have 2 controllers with the same class name (e.g. both are called TaskController), even though they have different prefix paths and live in different directories, they collide.  Both get dropped silently from the processing, so they are not found when a request comes in.  Hence the 404.

So regardless of the prefixes and route attributes, the classes need to be named differently to be included.